# Try to convert option api to composite api in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

All of the properties I add have a value, but there is still something that is not correct. I am trying to calculate the grand total by multiplying the price by the number of purchases, which is iterated through an array.

```
total () {
      return this.items.reduce((total, item) => {
        return total + item.qty * item.price
      }, 0)
    }
```

I try to change to composite api  118:12  error  Parsing error: Missing semicolon. (48:12)

```
    total () {
      return items.reduce((total, item) => {
        return total + item.qty.value * item.price.value
      }, 0)
    }
```

Comment: The snippets lack the context. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no `methods` object in composition api, so it's unclear why `total ()` property is intact

Comment: const total =  promos.value.reduce((total, promo) => {
    return total + promo.numboos.value * promo.price.$numberDecimal.value   
    }, 0)    The error is gone but  total always 0 how can I fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```js
 const total = computed(() => {
      return items.value.reduce((total, item) => {
        return total + item.qty * item.price
      }, 0)
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).